# Error using fmincon matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to solve a simple problem with fmincon but It returns an error message.
I have 2 functions f_2 and f_1 and I want to minimize each of them individually. I want to write f_1 and f_2 in a one matlab function i.e., my fun.m. Then I want to call each of them using an index from the main code. Here is the code you can see:

```
main code: 
 AA=[1 2 -1 -0.5 1];bb=-2;
      xo=[1 1 1 1 1]; 
      VLB=[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1]; 
      VUB=[100 100 100 100 100]; 
  for F_index = 1:2

      [x,fval]=fmincon(@myfun,xo,AA,bb,[],[],VLB,VUB)
      end
```

%% here is the function

```
function f = myfun(x, F_index) 
 if F_index == 1
   f = norm(x)^2 - 4*x(4)*(x(2) + 3.4*x(5))^2  ;
 end 
 if F_index == 2
  f = 100*(x(3) - x(5)) + (3*x(1)+2*x(2) - x(3)/3)^2 + 0.01*(x(4) - x(5))
 end
```

Undefined function or variable 'F_index'.

> Error in myfun (line 2)  if F_index == 1
>
> Error in fmincon (line 564)
>         initVals.f =
>         feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});
>
> Error in main (line 6)
>         [x,fval]=fmincon(@myfun,xo,AA,bb,[],[],VLB,VUB)
>          Caused by:
>       Failure in initial user-supplied objective
>       function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Ok, in this case the easiest solution would be to define different functions, `myfun1`, `myfun2` etc. But the solution outlined in my updated answer should also work. Note that its better to use a `switch` statement instead of a series of `if`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message clearly states the problem: The variable `F_index` is undefined within the function `myfun`. Variables in Matlab have a scope restricted to the function (or rather "workspace") within which they are defined. They can be made "global", but that's not something you normally want to do.

A workaround is to use nested functions, where variables of the enclosing function become available in the nested function:

```
function main_function
    AA=[1 2 -1 -0.5 1];bb=-2;
    xo=[1 1 1 1 1]; 
    VLB=[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1]; 
    VUB=[100 100 100 100 100]; 
    F_index = 1;

    for F_index = 1:2
        [x,fval]=fmincon(@myfun,xo,AA,bb,[],[],VLB,VUB)
    end

    function f = myfun(x) 
       if F_index == 1
           f = norm(x)^2 - 4*x(4)*(x(2) + 3.4*x(5))^2  ;
       end
       if F_index == 2
           f = 100*(x(3) - x(5)) + (3*x(1)+2*x(2) - x(3)/3)^2 + 0.01*(x(4) - x(5))
       end
    end 
end
```

Now `myfun` is nested in `main_function` and has access to its variables.

Comment: But I want to have `if` I have 3 functions actually and want to optimize each of them in this way. @A. Donda

Comment: @Jamaisavenir, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Please edit your question and include some code that is closer to your actual application, so we can better figure out how to help you.

Comment: @Jamaisavenir, I edited my answer, please see whether this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind extra arguments using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
fmincon(@(x) myfun(x, F_index), ...)
```

Here, the value of F_index is evaluated and becomes part of the anonymous function.

However, these look like completely independent functions.  Why not separate them all the way, and use a cell array of handles for the iteration?

```
fcns = {@fun1, @fun2};
for F_index = 1:2
    [x,fval]=fmincon(fcns{F_index},xo,AA,bb,[],[],VLB,VUB)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about variables in/out functions.

Practically in any programming language, when you enter a function, that function can only access the variables that are created inside, or that are passed as an argument as `x`, `y`, `z` and `potato` in the next example:  `myfun(x,y,z, potato)`.

This means that in:

```
function f = myfun(x) 
 if F_index == 1
   f = norm(x)^2 - 4*x(4)*(x(2) + 3.4*x(5))^2  ;
 end 
end
```

myfun does not have any idea what `F_index` is.

One of the ways of solving it is declaring `F_index` as `global`, but I would recommend you rather change the function somehow, so it doesn't access out of function variables.

Comment: But U want to use `if` statement so that I can optimize all f1,f2,f3,.. individually. @Ander Biguri